# MyFaces 1.1 + Tomahawk + TabChangeListener

Tags: tabs, listener, myfaces, tomahawk

The javadoc for MyFaces Tomahawk TabChangeListener says for the type attribute:

> This attribute may also be an EL expression that returns a TabChangeListener instance.
>
> Reference: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_tabChangeListener.html

My class implements the interface:

```
public class Teste implements TabChangeListener {
```

And in the JSP file:

```
<t:tabChangeListener type="#{teste}"/>
```

It is working, but its instanciating a new instance everytime I change tabs instead of using the class instance I'm providing.

Any ideas why or I misunderstood the javadoc?

Thanks in advance,
Sergio

Comment: I was able to workaround the problem by creating an static inner class and making that class delegate the event to my beam, but I don't really few ok with this.

Comment: The behavior you can see is expected. This happens because the listener does not implement StateHolder, so each time there is a request, the listener is created over and over. Implementing StateHolder, the state of the listener will be saved inside the component, so it can be restored later.